# Using `Replace()` method does not replace text in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache, replace, io, apache-poi

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Range;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;


public class POI {

    public POI() throws IOException, InvalidFormatException
    {

        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open("input.docx"));
        for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()) {
            for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
                String text = r.getText(0);

                System.out.println(text);
                if (text.contains("needle")) 
                {
                    text = text.replace("needle", "haystack");

                    r.setText(text);
                    System.out.println(text);
                    }
                }
            }
        doc.write(new FileOutputStream("output.docx"));


    }


}
```

This code is meant to replace text in `.docx` document. My input to the program is `input.docx` and it contains below data

```
needle
game
system
```

My output was `output.docx` and it contained the below data

```
needlehaystack
game
system
```

You can see the difference. Instead of "replacing" the word `needle` with `haystack` it has simply added `haystack` right next to `needle`.

I have no idea about what I am doing wrong here. How can I properly replace text in `.docx` files?

Comment: can you try this in your replace all plz? "^needle\\w+"

Comment: @KickButtowski: Now the output is `needleneedle` instead of `needlehaystack` which was the previous output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute no experience, but symmetrically, it should be:

```
r.setText(text, 0);
```

Comment: woooooow!!! You know, it worked! Can you explain me the theory behind it please? Because my original document got lot of paragraphs..

Comment: Just like this, can you please be kind enough to tell me how to access text inside tables?

Comment: I looked and XWPFTable is an IBodyElement, So see XWPFDocument.getBodyElement or [iterate](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#getBodyElementsIterator()).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `text.replace("needle", "haystack");`

`replaceAll` uses regex and "needle" is not intended as regex.

Comment: @Sniper I think I may be confused. What is the system.out.println for the replaced String showing? Is it showing the expected output? If that's the case, then it's not the replace statement causing problems at all, but the writing. A println of the getText after setting might enlighten us.

Comment: @Sniper are you sure that Compass way does not work? cuz it works for me :)

Comment: @KickButtowski: No it didnt work. I am using latest POI and .docx generated with windows word 2007.

Comment: @KickButtowski: Yes it is String, just a normal word.

Comment: @Sniper  why you have System.out.print(text); before  if (text.contains("needle")) ?

Comment: @Sniper please let me know what you get for getText after you use setText.